# It's been 3 months and my crickets still won't breed, lay eggs, or chirp

Tags: breeding, crickets

I've been trying to breed crickets for 3 months, but my crickets won't breed, won't lay eggs and won't chirp. I have a bed of soil (that I moisten daily) covered with a secure screen to keep adults from eating their eggs. I feed them Fluker's orange cubes, and I have a moist small paper towel for water. I keep them in a Rubbermaid container, and they have many egg shells for hiding and shelter. I keep them in a small shed and I have a small light over them. I have spent so much money and they still won't breed, lay eggs or chirp. What am I doing wrong? Any tips/advice would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Oh yikes, I've met people who have breed crickets and many who failed at the attempt, but I'll look into it n see if I can find further info.

Answer (score 3):

Crickets need heat more so than light. I'd try to get one of those cheap thermo-stickers. Try to keep it around 90 degrees. (Fahrenheit degrees) The chirping is the 1st thing I'd try to get going. Also instead of spending alot of money on cricket food. Try high protein dry cat food. Put it in a zip lock and roll it until it's almost powder. How many crickets are in the box? Can you post pictures of the setup?